# How to check user password in ldap whith java with given LdapContext?

Tags: java, authentication, web-applications, ldap

I do have a web-application, where users must log in. The password is stored in a LDAP server. All information about the LDAP server are stored in the application server (glassfish) as external jndi resource. So my application does no know anything about the LDAP server and only gets a LdapContext like this:

```
@Resource(name = "ldap/users")
private LdapContext ctx;
```

With this context it is easy to change or read the information stored for the users, but how do i check their passwords?
Normally i would just do a new connection to check a users password. Like this:

```
Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://localhost:389/o=JNDITutorial");

env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "cn=S. User, ou=NewHires, o=JNDITutorial");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "mysecret");

DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
```

But since i don't know the this parameters i can't do this. So how do i check if the password of a user is correct with my LdapContext?
The passwords are stored encrypted (ssha) so i can not just compare the attributes.

Thanks
Raffael

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be able to get the environment from the ldap context, clone it, and then put the principal and credentials for the user you want to check:

```
@Resource(name = "ldap/users")
private LdapContext ldapContext;

Hashtable environment = ldapContext.getEnvironment().clone();
environment.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, userDN);
environment.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, userPassword);

DirContext dirContext = new InitialDirContext(environment);
```

Answer (score 31):

This is a solution that can be used to authenticate a user with something else than the DN, for example with a `uid` or `sAMAccountName`.

The steps to do are:

1. Connect to the LDAP server
2. Authenticate with a service user of whom we know the DN and credentials
3. Search for the user you want to authenticate, search him with some attribute (for example `sAMAccountName`)
4. Get the DN of the user we found
5. Open another connection to the LDAP server with the found DN and the password
6. If the user is found and authentication works, you are fine

Code example:

```
public static boolean performAuthentication() {

    // service user
    String serviceUserDN = "cn=Mister Service,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com";
    String serviceUserPassword = "abc123#!$";

    // user to authenticate
    String identifyingAttribute = "uid";
    String identifier = "maxdev";
    String password = "jkl987.,-";
    String base = "ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com";

    // LDAP connection info
    String ldap = "localhost";
    int port = 10389;
    String ldapUrl = "ldap://" + ldap + ":" + port;

    // first create the service context
    DirContext serviceCtx = null;
    try {
        // use the service user to authenticate
        Properties serviceEnv = new Properties();
        serviceEnv.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        serviceEnv.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapUrl);
        serviceEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        serviceEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, serviceUserDN);
        serviceEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, serviceUserPassword);
        serviceCtx = new InitialDirContext(serviceEnv);

        // we don't need all attributes, just let it get the identifying one
        String[] attributeFilter = { identifyingAttribute };
        SearchControls sc = new SearchControls();
        sc.setReturningAttributes(attributeFilter);
        sc.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);

        // use a search filter to find only the user we want to authenticate
        String searchFilter = "(" + identifyingAttribute + "=" + identifier + ")";
        NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> results = serviceCtx.search(base, searchFilter, sc);

        if (results.hasMore()) {
            // get the users DN (distinguishedName) from the result
            SearchResult result = results.next();
            String distinguishedName = result.getNameInNamespace();

            // attempt another authentication, now with the user
            Properties authEnv = new Properties();
            authEnv.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
            authEnv.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapUrl);
            authEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, distinguishedName);
            authEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
            new InitialDirContext(authEnv);

            System.out.println("Authentication successful");
            return true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (serviceCtx != null) {
            try {
                serviceCtx.close();
            } catch (NamingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    System.err.println("Authentication failed");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Hello Nikolay, I also think that this is the preferred method as you can properly search for users by different criteria. I tried this though and retrieving the `distinguishedName` attribute always returns `null`. I think it is a better option to use `result.getNameInNamespace()`, what do you think?

Comment: Hello Max, thank you for refining my solution. In regard of obtaing a DN I believe it may depend of LDAP service provider. In my case 5 years ago on classic Microsoft AD LDAP it worked throught extracting attribute `attrs.get("distinguishedName")`.

Answer (score 2):

i have done same in my application.
following is the which might be useful to you.

```
    package com.agileinfotech.bsviewer.servlet;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import javax.naming.*;
    import javax.naming.directory.*;
    import java.util.Hashtable;

    public class Login extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet implements javax.servlet.Servlet {

    public Login() {
    super();
    }

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    final String SUCCESS = "loin.jsp";
    final String FAILURE = "Failure.html";
    String strUrl = "login.html";
    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");



    Hashtable env = new Hashtable(11);

    boolean b = false;

    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
    "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://localhost:10389");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "uid="+ username +",ou=system");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);

    try {
    // Create initial context
    DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);

    // Close the context when we're done
    b = true;
    ctx.close();

    } catch (NamingException e) {
    b = false;
    }finally{
    if(b){
    System.out.print("Success");
    strUrl = SUCCESS;
    }else{
    System.out.print("Failure");
    strUrl = FAILURE;
    }
    }
    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher(strUrl);
    rd.forward(request, response);

    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request,response);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request,response);
    } 
    }
```

Answer (score -5):

In real application LDAP servers, the password is stored in hashcode form and whenever any access manager takes the password from the user, that plain text password is again hashed with same key and checked to the one stored in the LDAP. So as such u can't get the plain password from LDAP server.
So if you know the secret key, only then you can decrypt it.

Comment: You can't decrypt password hashes, and there is no 'secret key'.