# How to implement authentication with Apache Directory Server and Client Java API

Tags: java, ldap, apache-directory

I am trying to build an application in which the users and groups will be managed in a Apache Directory Server and its client API.

This is an example of the ldif file being executed against the server when the app is starting:

`dn: o=koosserydesk
objectclass: extensibleObject
objectclass: top
objectclass: domain
dc: koosserydesk
o: koosserydesk

dn: ou=desks,o=koosserydesk
objectClass: organizationalUnit
objectClass: top
ou: desks

dn: ou=users,o=koosserydesk
objectClass: organizationalUnit
objectClass: top
ou: users

dn: cn=John Milton,ou=users,o=koosserydesk
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: top
cn: John Milton
sn: jmilton
uid: jmilton
userPassword:: e1NIQTUxMn1lQThmcUQzOVgva2xxSm1jOGlZK2JoWitUVFhzWElFRmZHeWJ1b`

I want to let John Milton being recognized as an authenticated user of **my app** when he enters the corresponding uid/userPassword. Something like:

`Boolean authenticate(String uid){

  //should i use connection.bind("uid="+uid, userPassword);??

  return something;
 }`
Note that John Milton being authenticated against ApacheDS (for acting on entries) is not the most important for me.   I just want ApacheDs to act as DB for my users ie **take the uid of my user, check the password, if it matches return true, either return false**.
May be this is not the way i should try to handle this, but i am pretty new to Ldap Protocol and stuffs around, so do not wonder if my problem is kind of weird!
Waiting for propositions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be a duplicate, but the second answer (by Nikolay Antipov) on the following question might answer your question:
[How to check user password in ldap whith java with given LdapContext?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522770/how-to-check-user-password-in-ldap-whith-java-with-given-ldapcontext)

---

This is a solution that can be used to authenticate a user with something else than the DN, for example with a `uid` or `sAMAccountName`.

The steps to do are:

1. Connect to the LDAP server
2. Authenticate with a service user of whom we know the DN and credentials
3. Search for the user you want to authenticate, search him with some attribute (for example `sAMAccountName`)
4. Get the DN of the user we found
5. Open another connection to the LDAP server with the found DN and the password
6. If the user is found and authentication works, you are fine

Code example:

```
public static boolean performAuthentication() {

    // service user
    String serviceUserDN = "cn=Mister Service,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com";
    String serviceUserPassword = "abc123#!$";

    // user to authenticate
    String identifyingAttribute = "uid";
    String identifier = "maxdev";
    String password = "jkl987.,-";
    String base = "ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com";

    // LDAP connection info
    String ldap = "localhost";
    int port = 10389;
    String ldapUrl = "ldap://" + ldap + ":" + port;

    // first create the service context
    DirContext serviceCtx = null;
    try {
        // use the service user to authenticate
        Properties serviceEnv = new Properties();
        serviceEnv.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        serviceEnv.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapUrl);
        serviceEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        serviceEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, serviceUserDN);
        serviceEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, serviceUserPassword);
        serviceCtx = new InitialDirContext(serviceEnv);

        // we don't need all attributes, just let it get the identifying one
        String[] attributeFilter = { identifyingAttribute };
        SearchControls sc = new SearchControls();
        sc.setReturningAttributes(attributeFilter);
        sc.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);

        // use a search filter to find only the user we want to authenticate
        String searchFilter = "(" + identifyingAttribute + "=" + identifier + ")";
        NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> results = serviceCtx.search(base, searchFilter, sc);

        if (results.hasMore()) {
            // get the users DN (distinguishedName) from the result
            SearchResult result = results.next();
            String distinguishedName = result.getNameInNamespace();

            // attempt another authentication, now with the user
            Properties authEnv = new Properties();
            authEnv.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
            authEnv.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapUrl);
            authEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, distinguishedName);
            authEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
            new InitialDirContext(authEnv);

            System.out.println("Authentication successful");
            return true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (serviceCtx != null) {
            try {
                serviceCtx.close();
            } catch (NamingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    System.err.println("Authentication failed");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the steps to do, i have implemented my way and  it solved my issue!