# User authentication using LDAP and Java

Tags: java, openldap

I am trying to authenticate user using LDAP. However, the passwords are SSHA hashed in LDAP. How can authenticate uid and password as I am sending plaintext password to ldap. Here is my code

```
Properties initialProperties=new Properties();
    initialProperties.put( Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    initialProperties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"ldap://localhost:10389");
    initialProperties.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION,"simple");
    initialProperties.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL,"uid=admin,ou=system");
    initialProperties.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS,"secret");

    NamingEnumeration<?> results = null;

    try
    {
        DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(initialProperties);
        System.out.println(ctx+"222 success");
        SearchControls controls = new SearchControls();
        controls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);

        String filter = "(&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(uid=" + uID + ")(userPassword="+pwd+")";
        results = ctx.search("", filter, controls);
        if (results.hasMore()) {
            System.out.println("User found");
            return true;
          } else {
            System.out.println("User not found");
            return false;
          }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return false;
    }
```

The sysout is always user not found as it is not able to match the plaintext password to ssha hashed password? How to convert the password to SSHA before sending to ldap?Is that the right way to approach this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`ContextSource.getContext(principal, credentials)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/ldap/core/ContextSource.html#getContext) to authenticate a user.

> Gets a DirContext instance authenticated using the supplied principal
>   and credentials. **Typically to be used for plain authentication
>   purposes.** Note that this method will never make use of native Java
>   LDAP pooling, even though this instance is configured to do so. This
>   is to force password changes in the target directory to take effect as
>   soon as possible.

The password is hashed for security reasons, you should always defer to the LDAP server to authenticate users, that's one of it's primary purposes.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any code sample to explain how it works? @Jake

Comment: Yes, I could provide some, but I should note that `ContextSource` is a Spring Framework class. Are you using Spring? If not, you may need to use a different approach.

Comment: No I am not using Spring

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522770/how-to-check-user-password-in-ldap-whith-java-with-given-ldapcontext) answer, it may help.